# Android TabWidget text space

Tags: android, tabwidget

Exists anyway to change left and right text space? Look at attached screen. So many space is wasted. They could fit without line break

Regards

[image: Screen]

```
<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/tabHost"
android:gravity="bottom"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
<TabWidget
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@android:id/tabs" />
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
android:paddingTop="60px">
<!-- First tab -->
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/tabStations"
android:orientation="vertical">    
</LinearLayout>
<!-- Second Tab -->
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/tabSuggestions"
android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing as I cannot see your xml layout code but i suspect you do not have android:layout_width="fill_parent" within it. If you do then post your xml and I will have a think.

Comment: I have edited first post and added xml code. I think I have "fill_parent" everywhere. What you see on the screenshot, is tabwidget filled with all width of my screen - this is ok. Problem is that each tab can't fit text when there is a lot of space